# Ex global command is silenced, why is execution still stopped on error (Neovim)?

Tags: neovim, global-command, ex-command

I have a sample text:

```
123
456
```

If I delete the first line, why does

```
:silent! execute 'g/123/d' | execute 'g/456/d'
```

work while

```
:silent! g/123/d | g/456/d
```

doesn't work, unless I bring back the first line, so that both patterns are matched?

Shouldn't `:silent!` make it execute completely (by suppressing Neovim's Error messages) regardless of whether it succeeds in finding a match or not?

Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the mechanics of `|` or `<Bar>` aka pipe character in this context?

Answer (score 2):

In your example you have a file with a single line `456`. If you run:

```
:g/123/d | g/456/d
```

you get a `Pattern not found` message on the first command and the second one does not run. It is a message and not an error (see comments), hence that is not the reason why the second command is not running. From Neovim's `:help :bar`:

> Note that this is confusing (inherited from Vi): With ":g" the '|' is
> included in the command, with ":s" it is not.
>
> To be able to use another command anyway, use the ":execute" command.

As @D.BenKnoble pointed out, the `execute` is making sure that the `:g` does not swallow the pipe. By using `execute`, you are doing as instructed by the documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. If `:s/foo/bar` fails, so does `:execute 's/foo/bar' | echom 'hi'` without echoing `hi`. The difference seems primarily to be that `:g/123/d | g/456/d` considers `d | g/456/d` as the on-each-line command (`:help :bar`). the `execute` prevents `:g` from eating the bar, so you have two separate commands.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble you are right in that I am wrong. ```execute``` does stop on error of the input command. Moreover, from the help on ```search-commands```: 'When no match is found you get the error: E486 Pattern not found
Note that for the :global command, you get a normal message "Pattern not
found", for Vi compatibility.'
So ```s``` throws an error but ```g``` only prints "Pattern not found". I will look into this a bit more and edit my answer.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble you are right, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @MehdiSlimani There is `:silent!` command in my original line: `:silent! g/123/d | g/456/d` that you and @D.BenKnoble seem to have overlooked. This should change how the line is executed, shouldn't it? After all, errors & other messages are being suppressed, so I think `|` shouldn't stop execution no matter what is the outcome, whether a pattern match is found or not.

Comment: @danko the command is effectively parsed as [silently] [for each line containing `123`, do] [delete, then if that succeeded, [for each line containing `456`, do [delete]]]. With `execute`, you have [silently] [for each line containing `123`, do] [delete], then if that succeeded (which it will because of [silently]), [for each line containing `456`, do] [delete]. See the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The difference seems primarily to be that `:g/123/d | g/456/d` considers `d | g/456/d` as the on-each-line command (`:help :bar`). The `:execute` prevents `:global` from eating the bar, so you have two separate commands. (Details on the structure at the end.)

This matters: in `:g/123/d | g/456/d`, if `123` is not found, _none of `d | g/456/d` runs. But in `:execute 'g/123/d' | execute 'g/456/d'`, if `123`, is not found, first `d` is not run, then `execute 'g/456/d'` is not run because the previous command errored.

Finally, by prefixing the *first* command with `:silent!` (`:silent` does not consume `|`, so only the first command is silenced), you guarantee that `execute 'g/456/d'` runs no matter what.

---

A small representation of the parsing differences:

- `:silent! g/123/d | g/456/d`: [silently] [for each line containing `123`, do] [delete, then if that succeeded, [for each line containing `456`, do [delete]]]
- `:silent! execute 'g/123/d' | execute 'g/456/d'`: [[silently] [for each line containing `123`, do] [delete]], then if that succeeded (which it will because of [silently]), [[for each line containing `456`, do] [delete]].

---

Extract from `:help :bar` to justify parsing:

```
These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
followed by another Vim command:
[…]
    :global
```

Comment: Excerpt from `:help :bar` helped me understand your statement "The difference seems primarily to be that (...)", namely the following: `These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be followed by another Vim command (a list of commands follows): (...) :global (:g) (...)` Once again, RTFM does wonders!